# Changing header content with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I need help changing what the text reads in a header. The user inputs the name on the first page and it should change the h2 on the next page to whatever was typed. Any help would be greatly appreciated and yes I add the Cookie.js library.
This is what I have so far:

Entry Page:

```
<form action="Lab12-p2.html" method="post">
  <h3>Enter Name </h3>
  <label for="name">Username: </label>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
  <input id="submit2" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<h2 id ="username"> Hi there! </h2>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#name").blur(function(event) {
   var test = event.target.value;
   Cookie.set("content", test);
   var ger = Cookie.get("content");
   $("#username").html("Hi" + content);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5 you can do this way also

```
$("#name").blur(function(event) {
   var test = event.target.value;
   localStorage.setItem("content", test);  
   $("#username").text("Hi " + localStorage.getItem("content"));
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hjqre6ru/

Comment: How do you use HTML5. Is there a way to do it with the cookies? Am i even close?

Comment: above solution work without any js librery. you can also use ur code which is var ger = Cookie.get("content");
   $("#username").html("Hi" + ger);

Comment: localStorage like a browser DB  save 'key value' data

Answer (score 0):

on page 2 add script

```
$("document").ready(function() {
   var ger = Cookie.get("content");
   $("h2").html("Hi" + content);
 });
```